# Why Regex patter matching null values

Tags: regex

My Regex pattern is

```
(\d*\.?\d+)?(\svarious\s)?
```

I only want to match decimal numbers and normal numbers and a particular string " various "

But in the result, I got the above-required result but with it, I am also getting null values.

This is my string `'Beginning Ending Profit 3.000000 % 3.000000 Loss 3.000000 % 3.000000 Capital 3.350845  % 3.346784 Check  if  decrease various  is  due  to  sale  or  exchange various  of  partnership  interest . % % % '`

I am only interested in 8 matches which are
`3.000000` `3.000000` `3.000000` `3.000000` `3.350845` `3.346784` `various` `various`
But I am getting 147 matches including the above 8.

Comment: You can use `(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\svarious\s)`. Not sure why you want to capture " various " literally.

Comment: Use the above comment's regex.  Your current entire pattern is optional, hence the empty matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are matching all indexes in your string because both groupings are optional. Effectively allowing to match any position in a string followed by nothing. As per my comment, you could try:

```
(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\svarious\s)
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/O8jnCk/1).

- `(?:` - Open 1st non-capture group:

  - `\d+` - 1+ digits.
  - `(?:` - Open 2nd non-capture group:

    - `\.\d+` - A literal dot and 1+ digits.
    - `)?` - Close 2nd non-capture group and make it optional.
  - `|` - Or:
  - `\svarious\s` - Literally capture "various" with leading and trailing whitespace character.
  - `)` - Close 1st non-capture group.

Answer (score 1):

The expression you are trying are matching 0 characters also (infinite). That's y you are getting wrong matches. Please try the following

```
((\d*\.?\d+)|(\svarious\s))
```